# Unable to call portlet resource url from javascript in liferay6.2

Tags: javascript, ajax, liferay-6, liferay-aui

I am using Liferay Portal 6.2 CE GA3
I need to call my custom portlet resource method from another portlet jsp file. Below is my code.

```js
<a href ="#" onclick="myfunction('sometext')">Click here </a>

<script>
function myfunction(myVar){

AUI().use('aui-base','aui-io-request','liferay-portlet-url','aui-node',function(A){
     var url = Liferay.PortletURL.createResourceURL();
    url.setPortletId("MyCustomPortletId");
    url.setResourceId('saveUserData');
    A.io.request(url);
});
}
```

and my custom portlet ...

```js
public class MyCustomPortlet extends MVCPortlet{
 public void saveUserData(ResourceRequest resourceRequest,
   ResourceResponse resourceResponse) throws IOException,
   PortletException {
  System.out.println("in save UserData");
  
 }
render method----
}
```

Here serveResource method (in my case saveUserData ) is not getting called. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try calling your method from your own custom portlet just to be sure your `saveUserData` method is being called and has no issues?

Please try and then read forward if it does not work ;-)

`serveResource` method is always named as `serveResource` and not by any other name as `saveUserData` when you use Liferay's `MVCPortlet`.

You cannot have multiple `serveResource` methods as you can have action methods.

So rename your method to `serveResource()` and it should work :-)

Comment: Prakash You are right. I changed the serveResource method name and also ,ajax method for calling in aui script is A.io.Request(url) ===>>    A.io(url). It is working fine. Thank you